Nucleophilicity order in polar protic solvent
The relative nucleophilicity in polar protic solvents of the following is
$\pu{1)}$ $\ce{CH3CH2S-}$
$\pu{2)}$ $\ce{CH3CH2O-}$
$\pu{3)}$ $\ce{CH3COO-}$

This is a question from my problem book. As per my understanding, the order of nucleophilicity in polar protic solvent should be reverse of order of electron charge density in nucleophiles.
Since $\ce{CH3CH2S-}$ has a vacant d orbital so it will have least charge density. $\ce{CH3CH2O-}$ has maximum charge density. $\ce{CH3COO-}$ will have more charge density than $\ce{CH3CH2S-}$ but less than $\ce{CH3CH2O-}$ as it is resonance stabilised. Therefore order of nucleophilicity should be $\pu{(1>3>2)}$. But in the answer key, $\pu{(1>2>3)}$ is the right answer.
Can somebody explain to me why is it so?

It's better now. Also, $\ce{CH3COO-}$ is acetate ion. The negative charge is delocated on two oxygen atoms so that it is the least nucleophilic among others.

@MathewMahindaratne Is it so? I thought vacant d orbital would have more delocalisation of electrons than resonance due to its large size.

Every time someone writes here "vacant d orbital" should cause automatic downvote. ;>

@Mithoron is it that wrong of a logic?

Your "vacant d orbitals" are as good as non-existent for p-block elements.
